# Как добавить title, description, keywords для каждой категории в php сайте?

Tags: php, html, get, seo

На самом деле добавить те самые тэги которые я написал выше я сам знаю. Но проблема в том, что мой сайт одностраничный (есть только `index.php`, а остальные страницы открываются по принципу `"$page = $_GET['page']"`).

На сайте есть пока 6 категорий товаров, каждый из которых записан в базе данных. Хотелось бы, чтоб каждая категория имела свой `title`, `description` и `keywords`.  Но, к сожалению, у каждой категорий нет отдельных страниц, типа `categry_1.php`, `category_2.php`. Они вызываются с помощью функцией `include()` в `index.php` в блоке `body`. А те самые тэги только можно написать в блоке `head`.

Связи с этим вопрос: есть ли решение у данной проблемы или нет? Надеюсь моя проблема ясна. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: создайте дополнительные переменные в скрипте
и заполняйте их в зависимости от `$page = $_GET['page']`, и выводите их в нужном месте)

Comment: "есть только index.php" - это называется Front Controller (http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/front-controller.html), а не SPA

Answer (score 1):

Всегда можо сделать что то типа этого:

```
<?php

$availablePages = [
  "cat1" => [
    "title" => "Title Cat 1",
    "header" => "Header Cat 1",
    "description" => "Description Cat 1",
    "keywords" => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    "file" => "path/to/file/to/include.1.php"
  ],
  "cat2" => [
    "title" => "Title Cat 2",
    "header" => "Header Cat 2",
    "description" => "Description Cat 2",
    "keywords" => ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    "file" => "path/to/file/to/include.2.php"
  ]
];

$page = $_GET["page"];

if (array_key_exists($page, $availablePages)) {
  $catInfo = $availablePages[$page];
  include($catInfo['file']);
  echo $catInfo['title'] . "</br>";
  echo $catInfo['description'] . "</br>";
  echo $catInfo['header'] . "</br>";
  echo implode(", ", $catInfo['keywords']) . "</br>";

} else {
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  echo "Wrong Category";
}
```

По сути массив являеться "белым списком" который хранит известные значения.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать паттерн MVC (разделение логики и отображения). При этом начинать генерировать контент после того как отработает логика. Если по простому, то не использовать echo для генерации странички, а сохранять все в переменную, а вывод сделать уже в конце. 
Чтобы самому не изобретать велосипед можно использовать готовые решение, например интегрировать шаблонизатор в свой скрипт (https://twig.symfony.com/) или использовать какой-то простенький фреймворк (https://silex.symfony.com/)